# Qt - Qt Command Prompt

Tags: c++, qt

So I found an excellent video where it teaches me about static compile. But in there it doesn't show where he got the "Qt Command Prompt" from. I searched alot but didn't find it in the directory. What do I do? Can anybody tell me where it's located? I even searched for it in Explorer but didn't find it.

Comment: My "Qt Command Prompt" was named "Qt 5.0.2 64-bit for Desktop(MSVS 2012). Try finding it by looking for 'Qt Desktop' in your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following paths:

```
<qtdir>\mingw\bin;
<qtdir>\Desktop\Qt\<qtver>\mingw\bin;
<qtdir>Madde\bin\
```

to your %PATH% environment variable, and the default command prompt (cmd.exe) will become what you need. Don't forget to restart an already opened cmd.exe after editing %PATH%.

What OS do you use?
For exanple, [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) you can find how to edit %PATH% on win7.

Comment: The problem is that I've to use the command "Configure" which only works in that Qt Command Prompt. I did what you said using your link but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The Qt command prompt is simply a normal `cmd.exe` session where the paths to the Qt libraries and binaries have been added to the environment.

It depends on how you installed Qt (using the SDK, build from source, etc.). If you used the SDK, a shortcut should have been installed in your Start menu. My Qt command prompt is at:

```
C:\Qt\4.8.2\bin\qtvars.bat vsvars
```

That being said, I rarely use the Qt command prompt. If you use the normal Visual Studio command prompt, then navigate to your Qt "bin" folder, you should be able to execute the command you need, like `configure`.

Comment: I have the QtSDK, and the path is like D:\QtSDK\Desktop\4.8.2\msvc2010\bin but there's no qtvars.bat

Comment: Not sure; you could try to reinstall, although see my updated answer as it may not even be necessary.

Comment: Tried with Visual Studio command prompt but doesn't work. I can't even find the configure.bat file anywhere except the Symbian bin folder. I suppose that configure file only works for the Symbian release?

Can you give me the link to download Qt which you have downloaded?

Comment: The Qt SDK I downloaded is at: http://qt-project.org/downloads. If you are trying to build from source (which it sounds like you are doing if you are trying to run configure.exe), the Qt library source is on that same page, toward the bottom.

Comment: I'm downloading the Library now. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 8, just type "Qt 5.4 for Desktop" after pressing the windows button.
Actually in windows 8 just typing "qt" in start menu, will give you the suggestion.